# Entity Framework - MySQL - Datetime format issue

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, entity

I have a simple table with few date fields.

Whenever I run following query:

```
var docs = ( from d in base.EntityDataContext.document_reviews
select d ).ToList();
```

I get following exception:

```
Unable to convert MySQL date/time value to System.DateTime. 
MySql.Data.Types.MySqlConversionException: Unable to convert MySQL date/time value to System.DateTime
```

The document reviews table has two date/time fields. One of them is nullable.

I have tried placing following in connection string:

```
Allow Zero Datetime=true;
```

But I am still getting exception.

Anyone with a solution?

Answer (score 12):

@effkay - if you solved this it would be great if you could post the answer.

Also if anyone else has a solution that would be great too :).

**Edit:**

The solution can be found in the http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-connection-options.html connector documentation.

I needed to set "Convert Zero Datetime" to true, and now it works.

hth.

Comment: It was a bug in mysql provider for .net :(

Comment: Nice tip the Convert Zero Datetime, but i have the problem that i cant insert from EF to mysql table the value '0000-00-00', and i need to.. is there a posibility to insert a value of datetime like that from EF?

Comment: yes setting: Convert Zero Datetime=True  in provider connection string part solved this for me

Comment: updated ref link: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connection-options.html

Answer (score 5):

You need to set `Convert Zero Datetime=True` in connection string of running application

Comment: Works, thanks. Much easier than the coding solution!