# How to tell entity framework not to update a field?

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime, .net-3.5

I am using a MySQL .NET Connector and when I insert a record into a database, it takes the .NET DateTime and complains that it can't convert from .NET DateTime to MySQL DateTime.  Is there a way I can have the entity framework not update this field?

Do I just remove it from the entity model or is there a property I can set on it?

I have tried `Convert Zero Datetime=True` & `Allow Zero Datetime=True`  in the connection string, but this just inserts `0000-00-00 00:00:00:00` when I do an insert.

I have tried explicitly setting the `Datetime` via `Convert.ToDateTime(updateDT.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"));`, but this does not work and I don't want to have it to explicitly set the datetime for every object that has a `DateTime` field.  I want the database to take care of setting the date for me on inserts or updates.

Comment: Are you looking for [NotMapped](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.notmappedattribute.aspx)?

Comment: @DavinTryon - I am using .NET 3.5

Comment: Ah. Would you rather not save the date, or find a way to update it?  [This Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1902523/entity-framework-mysql-datetime-format-issue) might help map the date.

Comment: @DavinTryon - I tried that question. If I do that, it saves nothing. I want to save a date, but I don't want to have to explicitly give it a value for each entity that has it.

Comment: Dang, can it really be that hard! My initial thought was to change the SSDL, but I was trying to find another way.  Seems there might not be one.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737520/entity-framework-ignore-columns